# fuse.sshfs: can't use `SHOPT=val` in /etc/fstab

Tags: fstab, sshfs, fuse

`man sshfs` says:

> ```
> -o SSHOPT=VAL
>        ssh options (see man ssh_config)
> ```

However, if I try:

```
$ sudo mount -t fuse.sshfs root@10.181.10.99:/ /home/ravi/mnt/ravidroid -o port=2222,identityfile=/home/ravi/.ssh/id_4096rsa_20kdf,SSHOPT='KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'
```

I get:

```
fuse: unknown option `SSHOPT=KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'
```

How do I use arbitrary `ssh` options in an `sshfs` entry in `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: I am pretty sure "SSHOPT" is a placeholder. Try `KexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` instead.

Comment: Nope, editing the command-line `mount` command above, I get:  `fuse: unknown option \`KexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a version of `ssh` before [this pull request](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs/pull/53/files) was merged in, there are two ways to pass arbitrary options to `ssh` via a `sshfs` mount line in `/etc/tab`:

**Directly**

In the `/etc/fstab` mount options (or after `-o` using mount on the command line), add `ssh_command=`, and specify the `ssh` command with the command line option(s), eg:

```
ssh_command=ssh\040-oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

**Via a config file**

The smartest way is probably to specify a config file:

```
ssh_command=ssh\040-F/home/USER/.ssh/config
```

The config file likely already has the required options, and using it will make the `/etc/fstab` entry far shorter.

Note:

- The additional `ssh` is required
- The `\040` escapes the space character
- If you have a `,` in the command line, quote it thus: `\,`
- Versions of `sshfs` after [this bugfix](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs/pull/53) was merged shouldn't require the above, but the `-F` trick could still be used for brevity or for a single consistent configuration among many mount points.

Example:

```
ravidroid:  /ssh/ravidroid  fuse.sshfs  ssh_command=ssh\040-F/home/ravi/.ssh/config,reconnect,follow_symlinks,auto_cache,allow_other,default_permissions,uid=ravi,gid=ravi,noauto,users,x-systemd.automount,_netdev 0 0
```

**Testing / Debugging**

As `root` without `ssh-agent`, type `mount <mountpoint>` and check that it works successfully.

To get verbose `ssh` output: add `-vv`, eg:

```
ssh_command=ssh\040-vvF/home/USER/.ssh/config
```

You can also try the following mount options:

- `sshfs_debug`
- `debug` (extremely verbose fuse output)

Comment: The title of your question says `/etc/fstab`. How would this work with `fstab`?

Comment: I just added an example, HTH.

Answer (score 1):

```
-o SSHOPT=VAL
```

is just bogus key=value, where the `SSHOPT` needs to be replaced by the SSH option you want to set (in your case `KexAlgorithms`). Therefore the correct command should look like

```
$ sudo mount -t fuse.sshfs root@10.181.10.99:/ /home/ravi/mnt/ravidroid -o port=2222,identityfile=/home/ravi/.ssh/id_4096rsa_20kdf,KexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

Comment: Did you try this? `fuse: unknown option 'KexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'`

Comment: But it is a bug in `sshfs`, that it does not recognize this option. You can have a look into the source code, that this one is missing: https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs/blob/master/sshfs.c#L296

Comment: Thanks for the detective work, I've raised the issue [here](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs/issues/52)

Comment: https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs/pull/53

Comment: Quickest PR ever!